# How to open just one popup at the time instead of two popups at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple popups. But when you click on a number it opens both popups instead of the popup that belongs to the number. Can anybody help me?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //open popup
 $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
 });
  
 
 //close popup
 $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
  if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
  }
 });
 //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
 $(document).keyup(function(event){
     if(event.which=='27'){
      $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.cd-popup-trigger:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 7em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">1</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->

<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">2</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```

[External fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5v1vpd1/)

Comment: do you mind sharing more code and more explanation :)

Comment: Its there in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the useful jsfiddle link, like that style lol

Comment: it's in the JSfiddle

Comment: `.cd-popup` is used twice. Both divs receive the added class.

Comment: change the line like this $(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');

Answer (score 1):

you need to set class to specific div next .cd-popup class not all the .cd-popup

change the line like this `$(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //open popup
 $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
 });
  
 
 //close popup
 $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
  if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
  }
 });
 //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
 $(document).keyup(function(event){
     if(event.which=='27'){
      $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.cd-popup-trigger:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 7em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">1</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->

<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">2</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```

Comment: Working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/fL0zcq8v/1/

```js
$('.cd-popup-trigger').click(function(){
$('.cd-popup-trigger').siblings('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
var close = $(this).next().find('.cd-popup-close');
var curtrigger = $(this).next();

$(curtrigger).addClass('is-visible').siblings(curtrigger).removeClass('is-visible')
$(close).click(function(){
$(this).parents('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible')

})
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section,
main {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */

.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}

.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}


/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.cd-popup-trigger:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}


/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */

.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}

.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 7em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}

.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 30px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before,
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}

.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}

.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">1</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
  <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <h2>
  Pop up One
  </h2>
    <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
    <ul class="cd-buttons">
      <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div>
<!-- cd-popup -->

<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">2</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">

  <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <h2>
  Pop up Two
  </h2>
    <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
    <ul class="cd-buttons">
      <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div>
<!-- cd-popup -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution: open the popop that comes right after the `<a>`. This solution isn't great because the javascript depends on the fact that the popup comes right after the button in the html structure.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5v1vpd1/2/

Better solution: tell each `<a>` which popup it should open, using data-attributes. This solution is better because the javascript doesn't depend on a specific html structure, you could have your popup anywhere on the page and it will still work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 //open popup
 $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var popup_key = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var $popup = $('*[data-popup-nr='+popup_key+']');
  $popup.addClass('is-visible');
 });
  
 
 //close popup
 $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
  if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
  }
 });
 //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
 $(document).keyup(function(event){
     if(event.which=='27'){
      $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
     }
    });
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.cd-popup-trigger:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 7em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger" data-target="popup-1">1</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert" data-popup-nr="popup-1">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->

<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger" data-target="popup-2">2</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert" data-popup-nr="popup-2">
 <div class="cd-popup-container">
  <p>Door het woord menu te gebruik ipv een hamburger menu herkennen mensen eerder dat het een menu is.</p>
  <ul class="cd-buttons">
   <li><a href="https://www.dailycms.com/artikelen/is-een-hamburger-menu-gebruiksvriendelijk/">Bron</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
 </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div> <!-- cd-popup -->
```

Note: You code has some small css problems (the button being over the popup), but that's out of the scope of the question and I'll leave it to you to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand a bit jQuery, is where your problem resides. If you analyze your code, you can see this in the JS:

```
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
});
```

1) You are binding in the click event of both cd-popup-trigger elements the same function, so the code inside it will run for both of them

2) When clicked, you do `event.preventDefault()` to disable default click behaviour (in this case is pointless, div doesnt have anything binded, but is not bad), and then `$(".cd-popup').addClass('is-visible')`. This last code, will find all elements with class 'cd-popup' and will assign the class is-visible, so it will show both of them.

A simple solution, just add a id for each trigger and cd-popup, for example:

```
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger" id="trigger-popup1">1</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert" id="popup1">...</div>
...
<a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger" id="trigger-popup2">1</a>
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert" id="popup2">...</div>
```

and inside the click event, you can detect the id of the clicked:

```
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // not needed 
    var triggerid = $(this).attr('id') // get the clicked a id
    switch(triggerid){
        case 'trigger-popup1':
             $("popup1").addClass("is-visible");
             break;
        case 'trigger-popup2':
             $("popup2").addClass("is-visible");
             break;
    }
});
```

Its not the best solution, there are way better than this one, but I think this will help you understanding how jQuery works.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code snippet:

```
//open popup
$('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.cd-popup').addClass('is-
visible');
});
```

But your first modal window under second hiperlink.